# Get all Post from Instagram based on some hash tags

Tags: php, post, magento2, instagram-api

I need to get all post from(including post name,post image, author name, author image) based on some hash tags, for example if i use the hash tag **world** i need to get all post which have the hash tag WORLD. is it possible to do this ?

Many people may use the hash tag, so how can i get these things from several peoples?

i need to implement this on my magento 2 website.

FYI: Some time i have to use multiple hashtags like World, Worlds.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook supports the "Hashtag Search" API.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/

If you want to use this API you need an Instagram Business account and a Facebook app that you couple with the Instagram Business account to perform API requests on behalf of.

Facebook has a useful "Graph API Explorer" which you can use to explore the Graph API and specifically the "Hashtag Search" API as well.